# How to find documents about SPO classes and properties, such as the ClientFormCustomFormatter property?

Tags: sharepoint-online, api

I found the follow PowerShell code. It works. As one of learners of SharePoint Online, I would like to know how to find these new properties and methods for SharePoint Online objects. It appears that Microsoft has not published SharePoint APIs documents for SPO. However, Microsoft did provide detailed APIs documentation for SharePoint 2010, 2013, and 2016. Could you please advise? Thank you very much!

```
#Connect to the site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Interactive
 
#Apply JSON Formatting to the content type
$ContentType = Get-PnPContentType -Identity "Item" -List $ListName
$ContentType.ClientFormCustomFormatter = $JSON
$ContentType.Update($False)
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: You can find properties related to ContentType object [here](https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/api/PnP.Core.Model.SharePoint.IContentType.html) and [here](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/cmd/spo/list/list-contenttype-add/#response).